# Javascript: calling functions with function as parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Not sure the title well describes my question but here we go.
I have a function (f1) that does some processing and uses another function f2 as an argument. In actual fact, f2 is "injected" in f1 and therefore the "signature" of f2 can be different (f2 may or not have some parameter for example). I'm wondering What is the best way to have a code that is as generic as possible?

Here we go with the code, which will certainly explain it better.
Traverse is my f1 function and scans all the keys in the object. For each key, it does something - that activity is performed by f2 who is "injected". In the sample code below, my function f2 is replacing a keyname by another keyname (here "lastname" with "theLastname"). The way it is currently written is not very generic as I have to write what the keynames are in f1. Also, say I have a simple f2 function that only takes the keyname to log it without parameters?

```
// f2 function
function replaceKey(object,keyname,newKeyname) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(keyname)){
      object[newKeyname] = object[keyname];
      delete data[keyname];
    }
  return object;
};

// f1 function
function traverse(o,doF) {
  for (var i in o) {
    doF('key : ' + i + ', value: ' + o[i]);

    if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])==="object") {
      //going on step down in the object tree!!
      traverse(o[i],doF);
    } else {
      doF(o,"lastname","theLastname"); // this is dependant on f2 signature - would like to make it more generic
    }
  }
  return o;
};


traverse(userList,replaceKey);
```

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
// f1 function
function traverse(o,doF) {
  for (var i in o) {
    doF('key : ' + i + ', value: ' + o[i]);

    if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])==="object") {
      //going on step down in the object tree!!
      traverse(o[i],doF);
    } else {
      doF(o);
    }
  }
  return o;
};
```

So that I can have:

```
traverse(userList,replaceKey);
traverse(userList,log);
```

Any idea how to write it to make f1 independant of the f2 "signature"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. What is `doF` (i.e. `replaceKey`) supposed to do with just one parameter?

Comment: `delete data[keyname];` - should that be `delete object[keyname];`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want your method f1 not to depend on any type of f2 you pass to it. One way to achieve it is to use a method factory.

```
function createReplacer(keyname, newKeyname){
    return function(object) {
       if (object.hasOwnProperty(keyname)){
          object[newKeyname] = object[keyname];
          delete data[keyname];
        }
        return object;
    };
};
```

Now you can create a specific version of the key replacer by:

```
var replaceKey = createReplacer("lastname","theLastname");
```

Now you can have your f2 that encapsulates the non-generic parameters scoped inside. So f1 can be done as you wished for.... I think... just pass the replaceKey as DoF

Comment: Many thanks Vladimir - that's very neat and was exactly what I was looking for.